# How to assign pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++

I have such method

```
void TetStreamRender::releaseManagerAndGetNextOne(TetFrameManager * manager,
                                                      ObjPool<TetFrameManager> * objPool,
                                                      SafeQueue<TetFrameManager *> * fifo)
    {
        ...

        manager = fifo->dequeue();
    }
```

also method `fifo->dequeue()` return `TetFrameManager *`, so I assume that manager should get new pointer returned by `dequeue()` method. So, I pass to `releaseManagerAndGetNextOne()` pointer to `TetFrameManager` and at the end I expect that this pointer get new pointer, but it doesn't.

Actually if I change this method like this

```
TetFrameManager * TetStreamRender::releaseManagerAndGetNextOne(TetFrameManager * manager,
                                                      ObjPool<TetFrameManager> * objPool,
                                                      SafeQueue<TetFrameManager *> * fifo)
    {
        ...

        return fifo->dequeue();
    }
```

It works fine. But question is why in my first example pointer assignment doesn't work as expected?

Comment: The way you do it in your first method, your pass a copy of the pointer, and then assign `fifo->dequeue()` to that copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass reference to pointer like:

```cpp
void TetStreamRender::releaseManagerAndGetNextOne(TetFrameManager *& manager,
                                                  ObjPool<TetFrameManager> * objPool,
                                                  SafeQueue<TetFrameManager *> * fifo)
{
    // ...
    manager = fifo->dequeue();
}
```